# All possible combinations of letters, digits and hyphens where there are non consecutive hyphens and no more than two consecutive digits

Tags: regex, validation

I need help getting the regular expression that validates the following:

> All possible combinations of letters, digits and hyphens where there are non consecutive hyphens and no more than two consecutive digits.

With the condition of only being able to use +, *, ?, |, (), [a-zA-Z], [0-9], _, -, {a, b}.

For example, I have been able to do the following:

- All possible combinations between digits and letters where no more than two consecutive digits: `[0-9]?[0-9]?(([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]?[0-9]?)*[a-zA-Z]*)*`.
- All possible combinations between digits and hyphens where there are no more than two consecutive digits and non consecutive hyphens: `[0-9]?[0-9]?(((-|_)[0-9][0-9]?)*)*(_|-)?`.
- All possible combinations of letters and hyphens where non consecutive hyphens: `(-|_)?([a-zA-Z]+(-|_)?)*`.

Thanks for your help!

**Examples**

- `ahj89_` is valid
- `h789_` is invalid
- `nd79_-` is invalid
- `_9-bh89` is valid
- `8_jj-m_` is valid

Here some unit tests: https://regex101.com/r/eM8AhH/4

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Lookarounds seem to be appropriate here.

Comment: @Jan, I’m not using any language. I do the test at the mentioned site.

Comment: You might want to make yourself comfortable with lookarounds then (hint: `(?=...)`)

Comment: @Jan, it’s not possible to use lookarounds. It’s part of the conditions. 

Answer (score 0):

This regex resolves any combintion of lower case letters, hiphens, underscores, and digits with no more that 2 following digits and no two hiphens, underscores (or combination of these two) together.

```
^(?!$)(?:[a-z]|[0-9]{0,2}(?![0-9])|[\-|_](?![\-|_]))*$
```

EDIT

I hadn't seen the condition of not using look arounds.

Still I'll leave the answer for anyone that can benefit of it.